# how to chnage appearance and look and feel of pop-up modal with CTools in drupal?

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

1. how to remove header in pop-up modal with CTools?
2. resizing of pop-up modal with CTools?

Comment: See the crooks modal example module included in the ctools module. It has a quite comprehensive documentation about all of them.